# Is it possible to create map to call Funcref (including lambda)?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, functions

Is it possible to do this:

```
function Foo(func_ref) abort
  nnoremap <buffer> <cr> :find_a_way_to_call_func_ref
endfunction

function s:callback() abort
  echo "123"
endfunction

command Test call Foo(function('s:callback'))
```

To be clear, `:h Funcref` is not `String`, it's type is `v:t_func`.

Comment: I like the question! But you might still want to clarify it. What kind of func_ref are you passing? A string with a function name? Or a lambda? I can see how the latter is a lot more challenging...

Comment: @filbranden v:t_func

Comment: Yes, in fact [`:help Funcref`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#Funcref) talks more about that and mentions lambdas explicitly... What I'm saying is that you might want to clarify your question with an example call of Foo (perhaps with a lambda?) to make it absolutely clear what you're trying to accomplish... As it stands, your question is likely to attract incorrect answers (such as the one with `execute`), which might not be the case if you had an example call that would make it clear that wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @filbranden I thought it should be clear as I use capital `Funcref`, but you are right, it's still confusing, I clarified it in the update.

Comment: Awesome! Looks pretty clear now! (Unfortunately I don't know that this is actually possible to do...)

Comment: @filbranden Would like to see the workaround even if it's impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really doable with `execute`... and `call()`

```
function Foo(func_ref) abort
    execute printf('nnoremap <buffer><cr> :call call(%s, [])<CR>',
        \ string(get(a:func_ref, 'name')))
 endfunction
```

Comment: Interesting, when closures were added to vim?

Comment: @MaximKim Around the time the lambdas were added (version 7.4.xxxx).

Comment: Wow, don't know how did I miss it! Thx!

Comment: @dedowsdi Ah, sorry. So you need `execute` with proper quotes...

Comment: This is cool,  never tried `get` with `Funcref`. Is it possible to get it work with lambda ?

Comment: @dedowsdi Yes, but you must ensure that lambda won't be dropped by Vim by that moment (i.e. storing Funcref keeps a referred function/lambda alive, but storing just a name string, obviously, does not).

Comment: @Matt Thanks again, learned a lot today.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to directly call this funcref from within mapping -- by the time you press mapped key funcref is already disposed/freed/unavailable.

You can try to persist funcref though (either in global or script local dict):

```
let g:my_funcs={}

function! Foo(func_ref) abort
    let g:my_funcs.f = a:func_ref
    nnoremap <buffer> <cr> :call g:my_funcs.f()<CR>
endfunction

function! Callback() abort
  echom "123"
endfunction

command! Test call Foo(function('Callback'))
```

[image]

It is not necessary to use dictionary, you can have regular global var I think. But for the dictionary you can come up with some clever things, like having array of functions, caching or whatever else.

Comment: Thanks, this should work. Will accept if no other better answer in a few days.

Comment: Similar to my approach https://github.com/benknoble/vim-simpl

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `simpl#register`? indeed!

Comment: Confirmed that this works with a `function(...)` including arguments, with a lambda and with a `funcref()` for a function that has been overwritten. Good job!

Comment: @dedowsdi glad I could help you

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you want to use the `execute` command, which acts like an eval:

```
function Foo(func_ref) abort
  exe"nnoremap <buffer> <cr> :".func_ref."()<cr>"
endfunction
```